# Close the gap between a mesh and a plane

Tags: vtk

I have converted an .obj mesh file to .stl. I also created a planar geometry as a holder for the mesh object then merge them. However, it contains a gap. 
Any suggestion how to close the gap vertically so that it becomes a solid object, I have already tried vtkFillHolesFilter and the manual way, but it won't fill the gap?

I have attached the screenshot, the red line from the screenshot is where i want to close it.[image]

The code to create the planar:

```
implicitPolyDataDistance = vtk.vtkImplicitPolyDataDistance()
implicitPolyDataDistance.SetInput(stl_poly_data)

#create a grid
xCoords = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
for x, i in enumerate(np.linspace(xmin, xmax,50)):
    xCoords.InsertNextValue(i)

yCoords = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
for y, i in enumerate(np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 50)):
    yCoords.InsertNextValue(i)

zCoords = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
for z, i in enumerate(np.linspace(zmin, zmin + 1, 50)):
    zCoords.InsertNextValue(i)

rgrid = vtk.vtkRectilinearGrid()
rgrid.SetDimensions(x + 1, y + 1 , z + 1)
rgrid.SetXCoordinates(xCoords)
rgrid.SetYCoordinates(yCoords)
rgrid.SetZCoordinates(zCoords)
signedDistances = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
signedDistances.SetNumberOfComponents(1)
signedDistances.SetName("SignedDistances")

# Evaluate the signed distance function at all of the grid points
for pointId in range(rgrid.GetNumberOfPoints()):
    p = rgrid.GetPoint(pointId)
    signedDistance = implicitPolyDataDistance.EvaluateFunction(p)
    signedDistances.InsertNextValue(signedDistance)

# add the SignedDistances to the grid
rgrid.GetPointData().SetScalars(signedDistances)

# geometry filter to view the background grid
geometryFilter = vtk.vtkRectilinearGridGeometryFilter()
geometryFilter.SetInputData(rgrid)
geometryFilter.SetExtent(0, x + 1, 0, y + 1, (z + 1) // 2, (z + 1) // 2)
geometryFilter.Update()
# ================ END creating a plane =======================
```

The code that merge the stl poly data and the plane:

```
meshAppend = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
meshAppend.AddInputData(stl_poly_data)
meshAppend.AddInputData(geometryFilter.GetOutput())
meshAppend.Update()
boundaryClean = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
boundaryClean.SetInputData(meshAppend.GetOutput())
boundaryClean.Update()
out = vtk.vtkPolyData()
out.DeepCopy(boundaryClean.GetOutput())

triangleTrans = vtk.vtkTriangleFilter()
triangleTrans.SetInputData(out)
triangleTrans.Update()

fill = vtk.vtkFillHolesFilter()
fill.SetInputData(out)
fill.SetHoleSize(1000000.0)
fill.Update()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vtkFillHolesFilter` is designed to fill holes and not arbitrary gaps between two possibly disconnected surface patches.

What might work for you is to stitch a "seam" between your freeform surface and the planar patch, as I have outlined in this post: [How to triangulate two non-intersecting polylines in 3D](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/How-to-triangulate-two-non-intersecting-polylines-now-in-3D-tp5746692p5746724.html). The idea is to go along the edges and to create new seam edges according to a simple heuristic.

Although the suggested approach works well also if the edges are not in one plane, it can fail if they diverge too strongly or too abruptly. Also, I recommend that the number of points along the two edges are roughly of the same order of magnitude.

[image]

---

**Update**: Find below a functional example that demonstrates how it could work for your case.

**Important**: The stitching algorithm requires that the edges are oriented the same way. This is naturally the case here in the way we construct the bottom for the surface.

[image]

```py
# This code has been written by normanius under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license.
# License:    https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
# Author:     normanius: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388962/normanius
# Date:       July 2018
# Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321415

import os
import vtk
import numpy as np

def extract_points(source):
    # Travers the cells and add points while keeping their order.
    points = source.GetPoints()
    cells = source.GetLines()
    cells.InitTraversal()
    idList = vtk.vtkIdList()
    pointIds = []
    while cells.GetNextCell(idList):
        for i in range(0, idList.GetNumberOfIds()):
            pId = idList.GetId(i)
            # Only add the point id if the previously added point does not
            # have the same id. Avoid p->p duplications which occur for example
            # if a poly-line is traversed. However, other types of point
            # duplication currently are not avoided: a->b->c->a->d
            if len(pointIds)==0 or pointIds[-1]!=pId:
                pointIds.append(pId)
    result = []
    for i in pointIds:
        result.append(points.GetPoint(i))
    return result

def reverse_lines(source):
    strip = vtk.vtkStripper()
    strip.SetInputData(source)
    strip.Update()
    reversed = vtk.vtkReverseSense()
    reversed.SetInputConnection(strip.GetOutputPort())
    reversed.Update()
    return reversed.GetOutput()

def find_closest_point(points, samplePoint):
    points = np.asarray(points)
    assert(len(points.shape)==2 and points.shape[1]==3)
    nPoints = points.shape[0]
    diff = np.array(points) - np.tile(samplePoint, [nPoints, 1])
    pId = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=1))
    return pId

def stitch(edge1, edge2):
    # Extract points along the edge line (in correct order).
    # The following further assumes that the polyline has the
    # same orientation (clockwise or counterclockwise).
    points1 = extract_points(edge1)
    points2 = extract_points(edge2)
    n1 = len(points1)
    n2 = len(points2)

    # Prepare result containers.
    # Variable points concatenates points1 and points2.
    # Note: all indices refer to this targert container!
    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    cells = vtk.vtkCellArray()
    points.SetNumberOfPoints(n1+n2)
    for i, p1 in enumerate(points1):
        points.SetPoint(i, p1)
    for i, p2 in enumerate(points2):
        points.SetPoint(i+n1, p2)

    # The following code stitches the curves edge1 with (points1) and
    # edge2 (with points2) together based on a simple growing scheme.

    # Pick a first stitch between points1[0] and its closest neighbor
    # of points2.
    i1Start = 0
    i2Start = find_closest_point(points2, points1[i1Start])
    i2Start += n1 # offset to reach the points2

    # Initialize
    i1 = i1Start
    i2 = i2Start
    p1 = np.asarray(points.GetPoint(i1))
    p2 = np.asarray(points.GetPoint(i2))
    mask = np.zeros(n1+n2, dtype=bool)
    count = 0
    while not np.all(mask):
        count += 1
        i1Candidate = (i1+1)%n1
        i2Candidate = (i2+1-n1)%n2+n1
        p1Candidate = np.asarray(points.GetPoint(i1Candidate))
        p2Candidate = np.asarray(points.GetPoint(i2Candidate))
        diffEdge12C = np.linalg.norm(p1-p2Candidate)
        diffEdge21C = np.linalg.norm(p2-p1Candidate)

        mask[i1] = True
        mask[i2] = True
        if diffEdge12C < diffEdge21C:
            triangle = vtk.vtkTriangle()
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(0,i1)
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(1,i2)
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(2,i2Candidate)
            cells.InsertNextCell(triangle)
            i2 = i2Candidate
            p2 = p2Candidate
        else:
            triangle = vtk.vtkTriangle()
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(0,i1)
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(1,i2)
            triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(2,i1Candidate)
            cells.InsertNextCell(triangle)
            i1 = i1Candidate
            p1 = p1Candidate

    # Add the last triangle.
    i1Candidate = (i1+1)%n1
    i2Candidate = (i2+1-n1)%n2+n1
    if (i1Candidate <= i1Start) or (i2Candidate <= i2Start):
        if i1Candidate <= i1Start:
            iC = i1Candidate
        else:
            iC = i2Candidate
        triangle = vtk.vtkTriangle()
        triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(0,i1)
        triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(1,i2)
        triangle.GetPointIds().SetId(2,iC)
        cells.InsertNextCell(triangle)

    poly = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    poly.SetPoints(points)
    poly.SetPolys(cells)
    poly.BuildLinks()

    return poly

def add_to_renderer(renderer, item, color, opacity=1., linewidth=None):
    colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetScalarVisibility(False)
    if hasattr(item, 'GetOutputPort'):
        mapper.SetInputConnection(item.GetOutputPort())
    elif isinstance(item, vtk.vtkPolyData):
        mapper.SetInputData(item)
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d(color))
    actor.GetProperty().SetOpacity(opacity)
    if linewidth:
        actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(linewidth)
    renderer.AddActor(actor)
    return mapper, actor

################################################################################
def run():
    # Retrieve the original stl file.
    reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()
    reader.SetFileName('improve.stl')
    reader.Update()

    # Extract the boundary edge in a continuous order.
    edge1 = vtk.vtkFeatureEdges()
    edge1.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
    edge1.SetBoundaryEdges(1)
    edge1.SetFeatureEdges(0)
    edge1.SetNonManifoldEdges(0)
    edge1.SetManifoldEdges(0)
    edge1.Update()
    boundaryStrips = vtk.vtkStripper()
    boundaryStrips.SetInputConnection(edge1.GetOutputPort())
    boundaryStrips.Update()
    edge1 = boundaryStrips.GetOutput()

    # Project the boundary edge to xy-plane.
    edge2 = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    edge2.DeepCopy(edge1)
    points2 = edge2.GetPoints()
    for i in range(edge2.GetNumberOfPoints()):
        p = list(points2.GetPoint(i))
        p[2] = 1125
        points2.SetPoint(i, p)

    bottom = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    bottom.DeepCopy(reader.GetOutput())
    points = bottom.GetPoints()
    for i in range(points.GetNumberOfPoints()):
        p = list(points.GetPoint(i))
        p[2] = 1125
        points.SetPoint(i, p)

    # Perform the stitching.
    # Requirement: edge1 and edge2 must be oriented the same way!
    #edge2 = reverse_lines(edge2)
    stitching = stitch(edge1, edge2)

    # Combine everything into one polydata object.
    combo = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
    combo.AddInputData(reader.GetOutput())
    combo.AddInputData(stitching)
    combo.AddInputData(bottom)
    combo.Update()

    writerFinal = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
    writerFinal.SetFileTypeToBinary()
    writerFinal.SetInputData(combo.GetOutput())
    writerFinal.SetFileName('output/test2.stl')
    writerFinal.Update()
    writerFinal.Write()

    # Visualize.
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    opacity=1.0
    add_to_renderer(renderer=renderer, item=stitching, color='blue', opacity=1.)
    add_to_renderer(renderer=renderer, item=bottom, color='red', opacity=1.)
    add_to_renderer(renderer=renderer, item=reader, color='white')

    render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    render_window.AddRenderer(renderer)
    render_window.SetWindowName("Overlapping cylinders example")
    render_window.SetSize(1000,1000)
    renderer.SetBackground([0.5]*3)
    render_window_interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    render_window_interactor.SetRenderWindow(render_window)
    render_window.Render()
    render_window_interactor.Start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. Just to clarify, so with your approach, it is required to have a planar too right? Because I posted the same question on vtk mailing list, and i was suggested to create the wall around the outermost edgest (please refer to this https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtkusers/2018-July/102250.html)

Comment: No, my approach does not require the edges to lie in a plane. It only assumes two closed edge lines that roughly face each other. The algorithm walks around the edge lines and inserts seam edges (using a greedy heuristic) such that the resulting triangles are as regular as possible. I'm pretty optimistic that this approach will work for the type of surface you showed in your post.

Comment: The other method is very similar. It first projects the edge lines of the freeform surface onto a plane, and then creates the "wall" with a seam-stitching algorithm similar to mine.

Comment: Yes, it does work for me, i just need to smooth the surface. Sorry i am new to these 3D stuff but base on your code, the part where you do points1 = extractPoint(edge1) and points2= extractPoint(edge1) means I suppose to have 2 shapes, right? For my case, edge1 will come from the original shape (the top one from my image), and edge2 will come from the plane (the bottom one which i manually created).

Comment: The reason I asked this question because initially, I only had the original shape without the plane but it was not solid and the vtkTriangulated wouldn't help make it solid (close the bottom part). Therefore, i threw it on a plane using the bounding box values returned from the original shape, then use the vtkAppendPolyData to combine the two.

Comment: I have tried the other approach since it does not seem to require to have a plane at the bottom. However, the wall does not cover up the entire boundary. Would you please take a look at my code to see what went wrong? I created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/ngunhaSO/f3902fd34172a161b678b2a05a5c91fe
I also added an STL file that i use to manipulate here: https://github.com/ngunhaSO/misc

Comment: One of reasons why your attempt failed was that `vktFeatureEdges` does not return a continuous poly-line. This is fixed by using `vtkStripper`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the clarification!

Comment: ...and the code, I hope you noticed that I updated my answer

Comment: There's a bug in your code - this line:  `i2Candidate = (i2+1+n1)%n2+n1` should read `i2Candidate = (i2+1-n1)%n2+n1`. After fixing this, works great!

Comment: @PatrickMineault You're absolutely right, thanks! I fixed the two occurrences in the code.